# How can i access the model instance used by a form from a template?

Tags: django

I am iterating over a formset made of modelforms in my template. I want to provide aditional information on that model. If the answer to this [How to Access model from Form template in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436430/how-to-access-model-from-form-template-in-django) question would work, i could do this:

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
Status:{{ form._meta.model.status }}
    {{form}}
{% endfor %}
```

But that just throws the TemplateSyntaxError: Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't think that's what you want to do. A model is a *class*: it won't have a `status`, as that's a field which only gets a value for a particular instance.

I suspect what you mean to do is access the model *instance* associated with the form, which is just `form.instance`.

Comment: Cool. However I have CreateView with form. When I use {{form.instance}} or {{form.instance.get_absolute_url}} it gives just empty string. Why?

Comment: Probably, previous is because in CreateView I have not the .instance yet (before the .save method). However can I access .get_absolute_url in such case? Yes, I understand, this needs new question.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a property on the form that reads the value then you can access it very easily in the template.

```
class SomeForm(...):
  @property
  def status(self):
    return self._meta.model.status

...

       {{ form.status }}
```

Comment: hm, thats a nice one. But as i have a bunch of modelfields i want to provide as basic info for filling the form, i don't feel quite happy about the idea to put all of them into the form...

Comment: Shouldn't that be self.instance._state.adding ?