# Django pass variables to form_class

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to figure out how to access fields from a Model that is used as a ForeignKey within the Model that the forms are querying.

Each `Room` has a form where the user selects a `Layout` from a dynamic list of possible `Layout` objects.

1—The HTML `forms/room/update/layouts.html`

```
<form class="layouts__form form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset class="form__options">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form.layout %}
            <div class="layouts__layout"> 
                {{ field.tag }}

                {{ field.choice_label }}

                <label for="value_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                    <div class="layouts__layout__thumbnail layouts__layout__thumbnail--{{ field.choice_label }}" style="background-image: url('### (I WOULD LIKE TO LOAD 'Layout.thumbnail' HERE) ###');"></div>
                </label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="form__submit">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

2—The form is being called by this in `views.py`:

```
class RoomLayoutView(UpdateView):
    model = Room
    form_class = RoomLayoutForm
    template_name = 'forms/room/update/layouts.html'
```

3—Which is being created by this in `forms.py`:

```
class RoomLayoutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    layout = forms.ModelChoiceField(
             widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'type': 'radio', 'id': 'value',}),
             queryset=Layout.objects.all(),
             required=False, empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ['layout']
```

4—Which uses the `Room` model from:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    layout = models.ForeignKey(Layout, related_name='template_selected', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

5—Which takes one of the `Layout` models as a ForeignKey defined here:

```
class Layout(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    padding_top = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    ...
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to='layouts')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-title',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am trying to figure out how to access attributes from `Layout` model within the actual form. I would especially like to dynamically load the `Layout.thumbnail` or `Layout.padding_top` within the form at the top. I have tried at least 8 different methods and was unable to figure out a way to make this work. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002182/how-can-i-access-the-model-instance-used-by-a-form-from-a-template), you can access the current instance associated with the form like this in your template:

```
{{ form.instance }}
```

So to access  the `thumbnail` or `padding_top` attributes of the linked `layout`:

```
{{ form.instance.layout.thumbnail }}
{{ form.instance.layout.padding_top }}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. The problem with `{{ form.instance.layout.thumbnail }}` is that it pulls the selected thumbnail for all the results of the form, not the thumbnail for each field. Are you aware of any way to access each option's variables?

Comment: I don't see a way to access the properties of the the related model (aside than the option label/value) from the form. I think you should add the list of `Layout` instances (`Layout.objects.all()`) to the context of your template and access their property there. Alternatively, you might also want to take a look at [django-select-2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#django_select2.forms.Select2Mixin.render_options) to render rich widgets...